# OnClick Scroll JavaScript in SilverStripe

Tags: scroll, onclick, silverstripe

I want to make a single page website in SilverStripe. I want a smooth scroll on click using JavaScript but I can't get this to work correctly.

### page.ss

```
<article>
    <div class="bgs" style="background-image:url($BackgroundImage.URL);">
        <a href="" name="$URLSegment"></a>
        <div class="rows">
            $Content
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('.menus-nav-item a').on('click', function() {
    var $root = $('html, body'),
    var $this = $(this),
    href= $this.attr('href');

    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top - 20
    }, 1000, function() {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
```

I get the following errors:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /#who-we-are

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined while
>   calling the class attribute

Comment: sometimes it shows "http://localhost/#[object%20Object]"

when i'm calling the ID attribute 


var s = $("#Navigs");
 $root.animate({
      scrollTop: $(s).offset().top - 20
     }, 1000, function(){
      window.location.hash = s;
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer!

```
$(function() {
          $('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == 
this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
                || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + 
this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top -54
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });


 });
```